# How to remove duplicate documents from mongodb with python?

Tags: python, mongodb

**I have tried a lot of scripts for remove the duplicate rows in my mongodb collection but doesn't works for me, can i find someone here for help me.**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/") 
mydb = client.bafin
myCollection = mydb.officier
```

Comment: It's impossible to have duplicate records in any collection, as `_id` is a mandatory unique field. You need to be clear what you mean by duplicates, maybe with some example records.

Comment: my records contains name, first name, title, position, birthday .. i have a lot of records that has the same content but not the same _id

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic way of comparing any type of data in a single collection, and removing duplicates. If you have a huge dataset there are better ways to achieve this, but this should work for general use.

It takes the md5 hash of the record in JSON format and compares it to previously found data. Any match and the record is deleted. Which version is deleted is arbitrary; you could specify a sort on the initial find if needed.

**Use with caution - this does delete data!**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from hashlib import md5
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_many([{'name': 'same'},
                             {'name': 'same'},
                             {'name': 'different'},
                             {'name': 'same'},
                             {'name': 'same'}])

record_hashes = set()

for record in db.mycollection.find():
    record_id = record.pop('_id')
    record_hash = md5(dumps(record).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

    if record_hash in record_hashes:
        db.mycollection.delete_one({'_id': record_id})
    else:
        record_hashes.add(record_hash)

for record in db.mycollection.find():
    print(record)
```

prints:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6054fb89c9cac53fbea4e130'), 'name': 'same'}
{'_id': ObjectId('6054fb89c9cac53fbea4e132'), 'name': 'different'}
```